# How do Neural Networks choose between more than 3 actions

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am coding in java am so that plays a game. I need it to take in inputs, all the normal weights and biases, and use it’s single output to determine one of three actions to take: jump, double jump,or duck. I know how to get the value from the neural network, though am not sure how to use it to choose one of the three actions. If there were two actions, I would do a simple sigmoid function and use >0.5 and <0.5.

Comment: Well, can you multi class logistic regression with each having predefined distribution?

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate?

Comment: You can use the same sigmoid function but now (x,y) where x takes say {0, 0.33}, {0.33, 0.67}, {0.67, 1} and for each case y should take {0,1}. You can search for Multiclass logistic regression: https://acadgild.com/blog/logistic-regression-multiclass-classification

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan Wait so should my weights be random numbers between -1 and 1? This way they are evenly distributed? Can you explain how it is done with the program that tells what number you drew?They have 10 outputs yet pull away one digit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Softmax activation function in the last layer of neural network for multi class.